# Retrieve key from Value Dictionary Array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I would to know how to get key if I have the values. Which class get higher marks?

```
let higherMarks = [
"ClassA": [10,20,30,40,50,60],
"ClassB": [15,25,35,45,55,65],
"ClassC": [18,28,38,48,58,68],
]

var largest = 0

var className = ""

for (classTypes, marks) in higherMarks {
for mark in marks {
    if mark > largest {
        largest = mark
    }   
  }
}
print(largest)
```

Comment: You already know the answer. You even gave it a variable name: `classTypes`...

Comment: Hi Moritz, I really stuck in Swift programming. How to print it out in playground ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What I'm saying in my comment is that you need to get the `classTypes` when you get the `mark`. Because when you get the higher mark, you want to also get the corresponding key value.

Keeping your code's logic I would do something like this:

```
let higherMarks = [
    "ClassA": [10,20,30,40,50,60],
    "ClassB": [15,25,35,45,55,65],
    "ClassC": [18,28,38,48,58,68],
]

func findBestClass(in results: [String: [Int]]) -> (name: String, score: Int) {
    var largest = 0
    var type = ""
    for (classType, marks) in results {
        if let max = marks.max(), max > largest {
            largest = max
            type = classType
        }
    }
    return (type, largest)
}

let best = findBestClass(in: higherMarks)

print("The best class is \(best.name) with a score of \(best.score).")
```

I just replaced your inner loop with `.max()` and changed the name of the key variable because it should not be plural. My method also returns a tuple because I find it relevant in this situation. But I didn't change your logic, so you can see what I meant by "also get the classTypes".

Comment: Thanks Moritz for the guide and explaination. I will study it. I really new to swift programming.